# Where can I purchase a replacement wattage limiter?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a Hunter ceiling fan with a light kit.  This does not come with a remote control.  After years of service and correct operation the fan still works fine but the lights stopped working.  I checked the pull switch and it is fine. After researching on line was able to isolate the problem.  The Hunter Part # 98480-02 Wattage limiter controller is bad.  Does anyone know where a replacement can be purchased.

Comment: Sorry, but this question seems a bit off-topic for the DIY SE. We generally discourage product recommendations in the first place, and questions asking where to buy a product might not be broadly applicable, so they won't help many other people. You might try calling the manufacturer (Hunter) to see if they can sell you a replacement.

Comment: @HariGanti, I'd disagree.  Knowing where to get parts is a big part of DIY, and someone carrying parts for repairing this Hunter would likely have other parts for other DIY repairs as well...

Comment: @poorplanning - [Shopping is as off-topic here](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions) as it is on [most other SE sites](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: @brhans, OP isn't asking for a recommended product, which would be off topic.  OP wants to fix a fan.  If you want, edit the question to ask how to fix the fan.  The answer I provided still covers that scenario, too.  Whatever floats your boat...

Comment: you need a new capacitor pack. you can make one yourself($), get them on ebay,($$), or order a replacement part ($$$).

Comment: I think this could be modified in such a way as to be broadly helpful. Ex: What is the best way to find specific replacements parts for a broken appliance? Not to be too banal, but an answer might simply be, "Call the manufacturer to request a replacement part."

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently replace the current pull switch and remove the wattage limiter to correct the problem (detailed here: [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/electrical/comments/266l1w/ceiling_fan_wattage_limiter/)

If you want to order a replacement, Hunter (the manufacturer) may have them ([Hunter](https://www.hunterceilingfanstore.com/index.htm)).  I also found [this site](http://www.ceilingfanremotecontrols.com/fan_limiter_.html) and [this site](http://www.ceilingfanparts.net/Ceiling_fan_parts_-_Light_limi/ceiling_fan_parts_-_light_limi.html) which seems to sell them (no experience with them)

Note that any electrical modifications may carry risk, which you assume entirely.

Comment: The local fan store told me when they install a Hunter fan they disable or bypass the wattage limiter because they are failure prone. I personally agree with this approach because the purpose of wattage limiter was to prevent the user from installing high wattage incandescent bulbs, and virtually no one is installing these anymore. I installed several of these fans and just put in the light kit without bypassing the wattage limiter. If one fails I will find out how to bypass it.

Comment: I have just bypassed them in my home, the funny thing is they both failed when I changed from 60w lamps to 6w LED's 3 on 1 fan 4 on the other both limited failed within a week or so of installing at first I thought I got a bad batch of LED' s , power bump? Doubtfull as I have a large whole house surge protector, so I just removed/ bypassed both of them no problem since.

Comment: @Ed Beal, was it obvious exactly how to remove or bypass the power limiter for the light fixture? I assume this is a part in the light fixture assembly.

Comment: Mine was a simple 2 lead device that was open. After looking up the part number and figuring out what it was I clipped the leads and used a small wire nut to tie them together. Mine only went to the lights the fans were still working in both cases. So I thought it was simple.

Answer (score 0):

The most broadly applicable answer would be to call or email or check the manufacturer website for retailers that are local to you. This is always true when you’re looking for odd parts for DIY projects.

That said, many store that carry Hunter products may be able to special order Hunter parts. Home Depot would be one such store, but you’d probably have to call or go to the store to find out if they can.